# Cannot convert 'std::ifstream' {aka 'std::basic_ifstream<char>'} to 'bool' in return

Tags: c++

Can anyone help?
I'm getting the error in the title

```
bool fexists(const char *filename)
{
 std::ifstream ifile(filename);
 return ifile;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[The `bool` conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) is marked as [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) which means it can't be used in implicit conversions like this.

Instead return if the stream is [`good()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good):

```
return ifile.good();
```

Note that when use in an actual condition then that's a place where a `bool` value is explicitly wanted and the conversion operator will be used.

---

Or considering the operation you want to do, check for file existence, use [`std::filesystem::exists`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) instead.